# Is there any way to enable two-finger zoom and vertical scrolling in Dell Inspiron 15 5547 Core i5?

Tags: mouse, dell, multi-touch, inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 15 5547 Core i5 machine in which I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 via External Hard disk. I want to enable zooming feature and vertical scrolling feature in the mouse-pad. Is there any way or tweak that I can follow to achieve that? Otherwise, experience is getting hampered, mainly while programming.

Comment: have Dell Inspiron 15 5547 Core i7 and vertical scroll worked out of the box for me.